# Wanting to populate data from the web to a directory on my desktop, am able to do it for one ID but not for 4 IDs?

Tags: python, csv

I am getting data from wunderground.com and then cleaning it up and saving it into csv files. I have an outside file called stations.csv which contains the id's of 4 stations, I need to get the all 12 months of data for each station, so 48 files I need to save to my desktop database.

here is stations.csv:

```
KCASANFR131,37.778,-122.408

KDCWASHI48,38.913,-77.031

IBRITISH359,49.256,-123.245

KNYNEWYO639,40.755,-74.007
```

So far I am able to get the data from that website and save it to a directory on my desktop called 'database'.

Here is what database looks like after the code runs:

[database when first code runs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jNSmO.png)

So that looks right, I just need to replicate that for all four stations.

Here is the code for that:

```
import urllib


def getData(month):

    url = "https://www.wunderground.com/weatherstation/WXDailyHistory.asp?ID=KMDLAURE5&year=2017&month="+str(month)+"&graphspan=month&format=1"
    infile = urllib.urlopen(url)
    readLineByLine = infile.readlines()
    infile.close()

    return readLineByLine


for i in range(1,13):
    data = getData(i)
    filename = "database/0{}-2017.csv".format(i)
    outfile = open(filename,'w')
    row_count = len(data)

    for j in range(2, row_count):
        if(data[j] != '<br>\n' and data[j] != '\n'):
            outfile.write(data[j])
    outfile.close()
```

Now I am trying to edit that original code so that it gives me not 12 for 1, but 48 files, 12 for each 1 of the 4 station IDs from stations.csv.

Here is the code (broken right now):

```
import urllib

def getData(Id, month):

    url = "https://www.wunderground.com/weatherstation/WXDailyHistory.asp? ID=" + str(Id) + "&year=2017&month="+str(month)+"&graphspan=month&format=1"

    infile = urllib.urlopen(url)

    readLineByLine = infile.readlines()

    infile.close()

    return readLineByLine

f = open('stations.csv', 'r')


for elem in f.readlines():

    vals = elem.split(',')


    for i in range(1,13):

        data = getData(elem, i)

        filename = "database/{}-0{}-2017.csv".format(vals[0], i)

        outfile = open(filename,'w')

        row_count = len(data)

        for j in range(2, row_count):
            if(data[j] != '<br>\n' and data[j] != '\n'):
                outfile.write(data[j])
        outfile.close()
```

With this one it is giving the proper id's and month names but it has no weather data in it. Here is what that looks like:

[Picture of databse with edited code for 2017 data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OGCCh.png)

Last thing I am trying to do is edit the code so that it uses zfill(2) so that I don't have months that look like 011 but instead 11.

Please help

Thank you

Comment: does it work if you take the space out of your url?

Comment: @RishiG the space where it str(month)?

Comment: Just the space in the string ("...? ID=").

Comment: @RishiG I don't see a space there, but when I did that it created the files but there was no data in there.

Comment: @RishiG my mistake! yes there is one there! I closed the gap. Still the same, csv files but no data in there.

Comment: @RishiG just doesn't seem to be populating anything in those files, it gives the correct ID, month, year but no weather data.

Comment: Are you sure?  I just tried reading the January data from the first site with urllib, and if I include the space before "ID" in the url string it returns empty data, while if I don't include the space it returns the weather data.

Answer (score 0):

For the part about the missing data, check the actual urls you are hitting.  You can always try it in the browser first.  It looks to me like the space in the url is a bug:

```
>>> import urllib
>>> len(urllib.urlopen("https://www.wunderground.com/weatherstation/WXDailyHistory.asp? ID=KCASANFR131&year=2017&month=1&graphspan=month&format=1").readlines())
2
>>> len(urllib.urlopen("https://www.wunderground.com/weatherstation/WXDailyHistory.asp?ID=KCASANFR131&year=2017&month=1&graphspan=month&format=1").readlines())
62
```

As far as formatting goes, you just need an explicit format specifier in your string.  This should do the trick:

```
filename = "database/{}-{02}-2017.csv".format(vals[0], i)
```